# CSS Transition right

Tags: css, positioning, css-transitions

I made a little codepen with the problem I'm having:

http://codepen.io/sloveland/pen/dytDG

The transition is not animating when the menu comes in, but performing some kind of FOUC issue. The weird part is when I change the default position to right: 100%; the animation works, but obviously from the wrong side of the screen.

Comment: interesting enough: http://codepen.io/markasoftware/pen/nCsFk works when you use JavaScript instead of pure CSS

Comment: Relevant read: http://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that's happening at all, very interesting issue. It seems to be jumping to an on-screen position then transitioning to the given value (since you had it just barely on the right side you were missing the transition stage). This is likely a browser bug due to not rendering out of window responses in combination with `right` and `:target`. I'd report it to Chrome if you don't get more help here

In reference to fixing the issue, I couldn't get it to work moving from the right side. however if I changed it to the left side, [**like in this demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lcDBi), it worked perfectly. Perhaps this is okay for your purposes.